# How to monitor and console log all serial port modbus traffic?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, modbus

I have been trying to use one node.js application to communicate to a PLC through the MODBUS RTU protocol. I have successfully communicated with the PLC through the MODBUS TCP protocol. However, when I revised the same code to MODBUS RTU, I have been experiencing difficulties to make the application and PLC find each other.

the package I have been using is:
serialport
jsmodbus

Currently, I have tried to use different Modbus emulators to communicate with the PLC. One of them which was called MODBUS SIM 32 worked, which proved the connection and PLC setup is just fine. However, when I aligned the settings of my node.js application with the PLC, it just ended time out error. I have tried with the Modbus TCP option from the same package, and it worked just fine. But when I switched to the RTU option from the same package, I always got the timeout except when the PLC unit was rebooted. Then I found out that it would receive something through the .data function, which is as far as I got.

The code I have been using for the MODBUS RTU communication is as following:

```
const Modbus = require('jsmodbus');
const SerialPort = require('serialport');

function connectModbusRtu(baudRate,COMport, parity,dataBits,stopBits) {
  const options = {
    baudRate:baudRate,
    dataBits:dataBits,
    stopBits:stopBits,
    Parity:parity
  };
  const modbusPort = new SerialPort(COMport, options);
  const client = new Modbus.client.RTU(modbusPort, 1);

  modbusPort.on('open', function(){

    if(modbusPort.isOpen){
        console.log('Connection through modbus established.');

        client.writeSingleRegister(1,12)
        .then(function(resp){
            console.log('I wrote the answer.');
            console.log(resp);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log('I had it wrong.');
            console.log(err);
        });
    }else{
        console.log('COMport open failure.');
    }

  })

  modbusPort.on('data', function () {
    console.log('------------Data------------');
    console.log(arguments);
})

  modbusPort.on('close',function() {
    console.log('------------CLose------------');
    console.log(arguments);
    modbusPort.open();
  });

  modbusPort.on('error', function() {
    console.log('------------General Error------------');
    console.error;
  });

  return client;
}

module.exports = connectModbusRtu;
```

and the following code is what I have been using for the Modbus TCP:

```
const Modbus = require('jsmodbus');
const net = require('net');

function connectModbusTcp(host, port) {
  const modbusSocket = new net.Socket();
  const client = new Modbus.client.TCP(modbusSocket);
  const options = {
    host,
    port
  };

  modbusSocket.on('connect', () =>
    console.log('Connection through modbus established')
  );

  modbusSocket.on('error', console.error);

  modbusSocket.connect(options);

  return client;
}

module.exports = connectModbusTcp;
```

The main goal is after the main script called one of the above js scripts, it shall be able to pass a correct Modbus instruction through whichever the channel (RTU/serial port, or TCP/ethernet) to the PLC unit. Please see following for the main script:

```
const express = require('express');
const connectModbusTcp = require('../../modbus/connectModbusTcp');
const connectModbusRtu = require('../../modbus/connectModbusRtu');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Establishing modbus connection');
  const client = connectModbusRtu(9600,'COM4','NONE',8,1);
  //const client = connectModbusTcp('192.168.1.124', 502);
  req.app.set('modbusClient', client);
  res.json({ msg: 'Establishing modbus connection' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, I could get it flawless executed through the TCP code set, but not the serial port. Just wondering if anyone has experience in this arena or have an educated guess to start from.

Currently, I am at a spot that I would literally try any opinion.

Thanks!

Roland

Comment: Where are you defining your `COMport` variable? Are you sure your Modbus TCP code work? You don't seem to be reading or writing any coils or registers in it

Comment: When you say *MODBUS SIM 32 worked...*, do you mean you tried both TCP and RTU and both worked? If so it might help if you add your **complete setup and settings** within that software and the js code you are missing where you select the serial port and IP

Comment: The COMport is called in main script as:
  const client = connectModbusRtu(9600,'COM4','NONE',8,1);
  //const client = connectModbusTcp('192.168.1.124', 502);

Comment: The MODBUS SIM 32 is free software that connects the PLC through the serial port with MODBUS RTU protocol. The TCP portion of my code already works, it is just at the application side, we only have RS485 serial connection available which requires us to develop the MODBUS RTU portion of the scope. The settings of the serial port are exactly the same as my RTU portion which is: baudrate = 9600, COMport = 'COM4', parity = 'NONE', databits = 8, stopbits = 1.

Comment: Great, but you are missing the slave ID, I will try your settings and code on a dummy server to see if I can reproduce your issue

Comment: The slave ID is 1 as what has been specified on PLC.